# How do I map any given function over a list of values?

Tags: elixir

I am splitting a string on a character and would like to trim the all the items in the resulting split. I would expect the following to work as [`String.trim/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/String.html#trim/1) exists:

```
iex> "My delimited ! string of doom" |> String.split("!") |> Enum.map(String.trim)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function String.trim/0 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

  * trim/1
  * trim/2

(elixir) String.trim()
```

I receive an `UndefinedFunctionError` indicating the function `String.trim/0` does not exist. What I want is easily accomplished with an anonymous function passed to `Enum.map`:

```
iex> "My delimited ! string of doom" |> String.split("!") |> Enum.map(fn (word) -> String.trim(word) end)
["My delimited", "string of doom"]
```

Does [`Enum.map/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) require an anonymous function as a second parameter? Is it possible to give my desired function as a parameter?

Comment: While @TheAnhLe has given you the correct answer, I think it's debatable whether or not the captured function makes the code "better".  I mean I think the anonymous function actually makes the code a little easier to understand but YMMV.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci is there any published Elixir style guides or any illustration of idiomatic Elixir for passing functions as arguments? I am on board for writing clean and concise code.

Comment: There's this: https://github.com/levionessa/elixir_style_guide but it doesn't really address the question of using a capture vs. using an anonymous function (at least as far as I know).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `& operator`.
[Capture operator](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1)

Try this:

```
iex()> "my delimited ! string of doom" |> String.split("!") |> Enum.map(&String.trim/1)
["my delimited", "string of doom"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Though the answer by @theanh-le is definitely correct and perfectly answers your question, you don’t need a `String#trim/1` here at all. `String#split/3` accepts a regular expression:

```
iex(1)> "delimited ! string of doom" |> String.split(~r{\s*!\s*})
["delimited", "string of doom"]
```

Comment: The example was a little contrived. Passing an existing function to map is pretty standard for any functional language and I wanted to understand why my expectations were not correct.